# The usage of boast

Tags: meaning

We can boast about and of something. But we can also boast something. What is the difference then?

> The hotel also boasts two swimming pools and a golf course.
>
> The hotel also boasts **about** two swimming pools and a golf course.

Answer (score 3):

This is a different use of the word 'boast'.

People *verbally* boast 'about', or 'of' things:

- he boasts about his money.
- he boasted of expensive vacations

This is a secondary meaning of the word, defined in Cambridge dictionary as "*to have or own something to be proud of*". It is correctly used without a preposition in your example. The example found in Cambridge is:

> Ireland boasts beautiful beaches, great restaurants, and friendly locals.

Comment: I still don't understand. If I say "I boast my new job" it will be wrong. But it is in line with "to have or own something to be proud of". I have a job which I am proud of.

Comment: _Boast_ in this sense is used of attractive features that places or businesses have that make people want to go there. It isn't used of  things like people's jobs.

Comment: @user1425 because when a person boasts *verbally*, you use the verb the same way you'd use 'talk', or 'shout'. You talk *about* something. It's a completely different use of the word with its own dictionary listing.